# [Meta] Is BrewAdvice open to increasing its scope to include wine/mead/sake?

Tags: meta, stackexchange2.0

I proposed a similar site on meta.stackexchange.com.  The URL is: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5680/proposal-for-beer-wine-brewing-stack-exchange-site

Is this community open to increasing its scope with the hopes of drawing  a larger audience under stack exchange 2.0?

Comment: FYI, it's spelled sake. But I still like the idea!

Comment: I guess I'll just have to start my own thread for CIDER Stackexchange site?

Answer (score 14):

Yes, definitely. We originally envisioned this site being anything to do with home brewing, no matter what it is you brew. The focus is definitely on making beer, but the overlap to mead, wine, saki, soda, etc., is pretty expansive.

We also envisioned the site including q&a about other beverage related questions. Beer storage, food pairing, etc.

While I can no longer speak for the community as a whole, since we have an active community, I can say that this is what I originally envisioned.

So, if this response get's voted up, you can assume the community is behind it.

Comment: People seem to be voting up PJs response, but not the question...How does that happen?  If you want to see wine, mead and sake vote up the question as well!

Comment: Agreed! (Ya, I was the first upvote. What!)

Comment: I think this site has attracted questions for all types of brewing so far.  I've seen questions on mead, wine, cider, and I think I remember seeing one on spirits.  Perhaps the word "Brew" and the brown theme lead people to the conclusion that this site is only for beer brewing, but I've never thought that it was.

Comment: What Room3??? People don't use a beer bottle cap for their wines, meads and spirits?  I hear you 100%, but I like the little bottle cap hat on the "B" of BrewAdvice.

Comment: I like the bottle cap too, but most wine makers use corks, not bottle caps, at least all of the ones I know.  I'm just trying to say that although the site has a "beer vibe" to it, it's already open to the community Kyle is trying to promote.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I'm not bashing the bottle cap, I like it too.  I'm just saying that we actually already support the community that Kyle is asking about, he just might not realize it at first glance.

Comment: @Room3 I agree. If you ask a wine question on here, I don't think you'd get voted down. I think you'd get an answer. But we definitely give off a beer vibe. One thing to think about. If this community were to fully support beer, wine, mead, cider, sake, cheese?, etc., would all the beer questions need a beer tag?

Comment: ...since we have an active community...
I don't really think we are there quite yet.  It seems to take a while to see changes and results outside of a small handful of current users.  The site is pretty slow most of the time, IMO.  I am all for seeing other aspects of home alcohols, lets just be realistic to how long its going to take before a sake person actually answers a question about sake.

Comment: @brewchez ya you're right. I meant more that it's not up to Taylor and me to make decisions for the community, as it was when the site first launched.

Answer (score 0):

I'd definitely like to see that as I make a lot more wine than I do beer.

Comment: I tend to whine more than I brew beer too....Oh.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there significant overlap with https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Yes but judging on # of questions and users, this site seems much more active.

Comment: Ditto @[Kyle Boon]

Comment: It looks like there hasn't been any actual user activity on that site since March 3. Only community admin bot bumps.